# How to redirect users and integrate whmcs bridge using htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog and whmcs client area. For bridging whmcs and wordpress I have used the whmcs-bridge plugin. It allows me to access the whmcs area using the url,
/client-area?ccce=cart for page /clients/cart.php

/clients/cart.php --> /client-area?ccce=cart

Thus, all the pages within the clients/ folder are redirected to the /client-area page with argument (without the extenstion ,.php)

How can I do that using htaccess?

Presently I have this,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```